# Using ANY with raw data work but not subquery

Tags: postgresql

I just can't figure it out why this query work

```
SELECT id, name, organization_id
FROM facilities
WHERE organization_id = ANY(
    '{abc-xyz-123,678-ght-nmp}'
)
```

But this query wont work with error `operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]`

```
SELECT id, name, organization_id
FROM facilities
WHERE organization_id = ANY(
    SELECT organization_ids
    FROM admins
    WHERE id = 'jkl-iop-345'
)
```

When the subquery

```
SELECT organization_ids
FROM admins
WHERE id = 'jkl-iop-345'
```

give the exact result of `{abc-xyz-123,678-ght-nmp}`.
I'm using postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery produces one row that contains an array.

If you use `= ANY (SELECT ...)`, the result set is converted to an array, so you end up with

```
{{abc-xyz-123,678-ght-nmp}}
```

which is an array of arrays.

You probably want

```
SELECT id, name, organization_id
FROM facilities
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM admins
              WHERE admins.id = 'jkl-iop-345'
                AND facilities.organization_id = ANY (admins.organization_ids)
             );
```

Let me remark that storing references to other tables in an array, JSON or other composite data type is an exceptionally bad idea. A normalized schema with a junction table would serve you better.

Comment: Thank you, it work perfectly!
I too, feel like storing organization_ids in an array is a bad ideal, but i can't think of other ways. How do i express the relation that 1 admin can mange multiple organization?

Comment: If each organization is managed by a single admin, add a foreign key from `facilities` to `admins`. If by multiple, add a "junction table" that contains pairs of foreign keys, one pointing to `admins` and one to `facilities`. That sounds complicated, but works better.